# Post picture to a Facebook group using Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm have Ruby On Rails application and use gem koala. I'm using method

```
graph.put_connections(owner_id, "feed", { 
    message: generate_message,
    link: generate_link, 
    object_id: id_image 
}, api_version: "v2.0")
```

I need to publish a post with a picture in the group. At the current moment I upload a picture in the album. At the time of publishing I attach the id of the uploaded image to a post, but the picture is not placed.

Is only a message. What is the problem? Is it possible to post with inner picture?

Answer (score 0):

Please take reference from this-

```
page_image = @newgraph.get_connections(params[:id],"tabs/app_14548156*****434",{:custom_name =>params['custom_name'],  :custom_image_url =>["custom_image_url"]})
@user.update_attributes(:facebook_store_url => page_image["id".to_i]["link"],:facebook_store_tab_name => page_image["id".to_i]["name"], :fbimage => "http://www.yyy.com/thought_images/thumb0/232_images.jpg")
```

My code is -

```
def facebook_store_page
  #@graph  = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user)

  if params['user_id']
    @user = User.find params[:user_id]
    @user.update_attributes(:facebook_page_id =>  params[:id], :facebook_page_token =>params['pagetoken'])  
    @newgraph=Koala::Facebook::API.new(params[:pagetoken])
    @PagecustomTab=@newgraph.put_connections("me","tabs",  {:app_id => '14548156*****434'})
        @pageid   = current_user.facebook_page_id
        page_image = @newgraph.get_connections(params[:id],"tabs/app_14548156*****434",{:custom_name =>params['custom_name'],  :custom_image_url =>["custom_image_url"]})
        @user.update_attributes(:facebook_store_url => page_image["id".to_i]["link"],:facebook_store_tab_name => page_image["id".to_i]["name"], :fbimage => "http://www.yyy.com/thought_images/thumb0/232_images.jpg")
    respond_to do |format|

      format.json { render json: true}
    end

  else

  end
```